# Why are the surfaces of liquids always perpendicular to the gravitational force?

Tags: gravity, newtonian-gravity

I am not a physicist nor do I have a good knowledge of the topic. Pardon me if I use terms erroneously.

I observed that when I put some water in a bottle, without regards to how the bottle is placed, the surface of water is always perpendicular to the direction of gravitational force. What is the explanation behind this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean horizontal to the direction of gravity. The answer is simple. Any part of the water surface which rises above the general level is dragged down by gravity until pressure from the rest of the liquid prevents it from sinking any lower.

Comment: You didn't make it clear but the surface of water at a higher height is under pretty much the same pressure. There's a lower rate of change of pressure with height in that part of the water so it accelerates down.

Answer (score 1):

To add to other answers - you could also say that the water will, in most cases, not be *perfectly* level. In a smooth sided water bottle, for example, if you look very closely, you will see a raised curved edge where the water meets the bottle. This is called a 'water meniscus', and is to do with the surface tension properties of water. In small containers such as test tubes, the effect is very strong, and the surface of the water is in fact curved instead of level. In terms of forces, it is the electromagnetic forces of the materials overcoming the force of gravity.[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is the same reason that water will run downhill.

If the water in the bottle **is not** level, then the water that is higher will "run downhill" until the water **is** level.

Comment: I downvoted this answer because it doesn't appear to answer the question. You didn't explain why a surface has a tendency to become level. In the case of water running downhill, it goes down without any water having to go up in order to enable it to go down. In the case of a nonlevel surface of a body of water, in order for the water that's above the equilibrium level to go down, other water has to go up. You didn't explain why the laws end up giving precedence of that water going down over other water not going up. It just seems so intuitive that the natural tendency is for a liquid to become

Comment: level so you're basically saying because that's just the way it is.

Comment: @Timothy: I understand your point.  My next point might just be semantics...  The other water doesn't HAVE to go up.  If it didn't go up, the water at a higher elevation would still run downhill over the top of it.  You probably won't like the following answer to another question either.  https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/24698/why-does-gravity-make-everything-round/24716#24716

Comment: But the higher up water doesn't run down without pushing any water up. I suppose that if you show that it would reduce gravitational potential energy for the higher water to flow and spread out without pushing any of the lower water out of the way and that once the water assumes a certain shape, it makes no difference where each part of the water is for the total gravitational potential energy, then you can show that the natural tendency is to become level. However, I have my own way of thinking and don't feel like that's a very intuitive explanation for why liquids have a tendency to

Comment: become level. For my purposes, this answer doesn't add anything to Michael Walsby's answer. Other people are free to disagree. I still think it's worth the downvote because you didn't make it clear in the answer that it would be favourable for the higher water to flow down over the lower water.

Comment: @Timothy: I didn't make it clear that it is favorable for water to run downhill either, but you don't seem to have a problem with that statement.

Answer (score 0):

The math shows that when the liquid is level, it minimizes the total gravitational potential energy of the liquid. I know that in actuality, Earth is spinning and in Earth's frame of reference, the real natural tendency is for the surface to become perpendicular to the vector sum of the gravitational force and the centrifugal force. I know there is no such thing as potential energy of a fictitous force. However, when matter, gets further away from the axis of rotation, it causes Earth's rotation to slow down and have less rotational kinetic energy. I believe it can be show that when the surface is perpendicular to the vector sum of the gravitational force and the centrifugal force, it minimizes the sum of the gravitational potential energy of the liquid and the total kinetic energy of rotation. For this reason, we could define potential energy of a fictitous force. Then you would have to be careful to realize that it's no longer true that total energy is conserved according to this definition and it's just true that the total mechanical energy of the liquid is conserved in the frame of reference of Earth.

I don't believe potential energy or kinetic energy are real things that physically exist. They're just a complex mathematical property of the system we defined because once you define them, you can show that the laws end up conserving the total of them and use that to simplify calculations.

Comment: Not to be too negative, but do you really think that this answer helps the OP more than the other answers?  "The math shows...", "I believe it can be show that...".

Comment: @James Originally, I would have thought it was better not to write this answer then after reading your answer and seeing that it had a positive score, I thought well maybe other people have different standards so maybe this answer does add something to Michael Walsby's after all by their standards. neils neilson also suggested that maybe I could write my own answer. Then I decided to think for myself whether I really have an answer that suits and thought I guess this answer does suit. Even before I gained all that information, I was going to write this answer if Michael Walsby's answer

Comment: didn't already exist.

Comment: Also, I believe I'm supposed to feel free to do my own actions based on my own opinion and downvote your answer because it seems to not add anything according to my opinion as well as writing an answer because it seems because I decided to take other peoples opinion into account and thought other people might have the opinion that it suits. You're also free to show your opinion through your actions and downvote this answer. According to the answer at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147214/can-should-you-be-able-to-upvote-your-own-posts/197725#197725, you cannot vote for your own post

Comment: because writing a post already shows that you have the opinion that it's good. I actually once Google searched upvoting your own post and then found that question and then just now, I actually upvoted that question because I felt that it was useful because it would enable people to give a useful answer like that.

Answer (score 0):

This is because liquids cannot withstand shear stress or tangential stress ( solids can). Imagine the bottle to be cylindrical and assume that the cylindrical liquid column inside is a solid(hypothetical) .  Now as I tilt the bottle, the column also gets tilted as it is tightly fitted and it withstands the shear stress but liquid on the other side( if the bottle is tilted ) will regain its previous position (when the bottle was not tilted )as it flows  i.e it will become perpendicular to the direction of  gravity (direction : vertically downwards) .

Note - Above, I assumed that the bottle is not accelerating .
There might be cases when the bottle is accelerating (say horizontally) then the water surface will be perpendicular to the effective force of gravity (which is ofcourse not vertically downwards in case of accelerating containers).

Answer (score -1):

the reason why liquids assume level surfaces is that liquids cannot sustain shear stresses the way that solids can. Their inability to withstand shear means that in the presence of gravity 1) they assume the shape of whatever container they are placed in, and 2) the exposed surface becomes level with respect to the direction of gravity.

Comment: I downvoted this answer because I feel like you're missing the point of the question. I doubt the author assumed a liquid could withstand shear stress. This answer would only be suitable if there was a reason to think they assumed that because then it would resolve their confusion. The author probably wanted an answer of how given the way liquids actually work, how do you show that their natural tendency is to become level.

Comment: @timothy, I disagree. If you really believe my answer misses the point, I encourage you to furnish your own answer to this question that addresses the point. With all due respect, writing your own answer would probably take less time than what you spent writing critiques of my and James's answers here. It might also score you some rep points if the OP likes and accepts it.

Comment: I guess I do have an answer that suits. I originally thought it wouldn't add anything to Michael Walsby's answer but now that I see that some people like James' answer, maybe that general type of answer is more to add something to that answer after all. I was going to give an explanation using gravitational potential energy but then I felt like showing that minimizing gravitational potential energy really is the natural tendency is actually quite a hard thing to prove.